# Can I dynamically change the property in features.properties.{some property name} in leaflet geoJSON

Tags: leaflet, geojson

In geoJson leaflet, can I dynamically change the property in feature.properties.{some property name} 
Here's how it looks like:

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("PHL.geojson", {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    for(var i=0;i<leg.length;i++){
      if(feature.properties.ID_2===leg[i]){
        layer.setStyle({
          weight: 2,
          opacity: 1,
          color: colLeg[i],
          dashArray: '3',
          fillOpacity: 0.3,
          fillColor: colLeg[i]
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
);
```

I want to dynamically change ID_2. Can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my problem here is actually about object.
So, yup I already got the solution and here's how I did it.

```
var propName = "ID_2";    
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("PHL.geojson", {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    for(var i=0;i<leg.length;i++){
      if(feature.properties[propName]===leg[i]){
        layer.setStyle({
          weight: 2,
          opacity: 1,
          color: colLeg[i],
          dashArray: '3',
          fillOpacity: 0.3,
          fillColor: colLeg[i]
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
);
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp